# Why strtotime subtracts 2 hours automatically?

Tags: php, strtotime

I used `strtotime("YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s")` and this gave me a time 2 hours automatically subtracted.

eg: `strtotime("2016-05-11 00:00")` gave me `int(1462917600)` this is 2 hours negative to what I have input.

Which is: `2016-05-10 22:00` when i reconvert.
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.

So my guess is that you're in a time zone where 2016-05-11 00:00:00 local is 2016-05-10 22:00:00 UTC.

The integer result will *always* be in "seconds since the Unix epoch" which uniquely identifies an instant in time. To convert either *to* that or *from* that, you should consider the time zone you want to use.